How to count cul-de-sacs (aka dead-ends) in a maze using Python?
Problem Statement
I am working on a maze-solving program where I need to count the number of cul-de-sacs, also known as dead-ends. The maze is represented in a way that allows identifying different paths and intersections.
Approaches Tried

Marking Pathways: Initially, I marked all the nodes between gates and cul-de-sacs with an "X", then labeled all the possible routes from one gate to another. (so far the best one but cannot generalize all the test cases)
Using Intersection Points: I tried using nodes that have multiple openings as potential dead-end identifiers.

Additional Information

Breadth-First Search (BFS): I am currently using BFS to traverse all nodes in the maze, but I'm struggling to correctly identify and count dead-ends.
The maze is represented by 0 and 1 (0 = road and 1 = wall).

Question
What are the possible methods I can use to count the cul-de-sacs in the maze using Python? I am looking for algorithmic suggestions or Python libraries that might simplify this process.
Sample Maze
The maze has 8 accessible cul-de-sacs. The accesses are indicated by triangles

[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]


How EXACTLY is your maze coded?

@Swifty Thanks for reminding. I have just added to the content.

Note that the code used to represent your maze does not correspond exactly to your drawing (thick walls in your code, thin walls in the drawing).
Nevertheless I had some fun implementing a Maze class that extracts the "thin wall" maze from the "thick wall" data; I added a method to list dead-ends (by which I mean the actual dead-ends, not the entrances you marked on your drawing), a method to cut the maze branch leading to a dead-end, and another to cut all dead-end branches, leaving only (in simple mazes) the correct path.
This doesn't do exactly what you asked (counting entrances), but since your question was a little vague it's the best I could do. You can always build other methods on top of mine to fit your needs.
Edit: I tweaked the code a little. The .trim_maze method now returns a set of dead-end entrances (but the "double" entrance appears only once), and these appear in .show_work_state; the .count_dead_end_entrances computes the number of dead-end paths (so the "double" entrance counts for 2):
from copy import deepcopy


class Maze:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.work_data = deepcopy(data)
        self.height = len(data) // 2
        self.width = len(data[0]) // 2
        self.dead_end_entrances = set()
        self.exit_dict = {
            (-1, 0): 'N',
            (1, 0): 'S',
            (-0, -1): 'W',
            (0, 1): 'E',
        }
        self.offset_dict = {e: o for o, e in self.exit_dict.items()}
        opposite_dict = {
            'N': 'S',
            'S': 'N',
            'W': 'E',
            'E': 'W',
        }

    def node_exits(self, x, y, work=False):
        data = self.work_data if work else self.data
        if not all((0 <= x <= self.width, 0 <= y <= self.height)):
            raise Exception("Out of bounds")
        exits = []
        for offset, direction in self.exit_dict.items():
            if not data[2 * y + 1 + offset[0]][2 * x + 1 + offset[1]]:
                exits.append(direction)
        return exits

    def node_repr(self, x, y, work=False):
        ne = self.node_exits(x, y, work)
        return(
            f'   {" | " if "N" in ne else "   "}   ',
            f'{"---" if "W" in ne else "   "}{" x " if len(ne) == 1 else " o "}{"---" if "E" in ne else "   "}',
            f'   {" | " if "S" in ne else "   "}   ')

    def node_print(self, x, y, work=False):
        print('\n'.join(self.node_repr(x, y, work)))

    def __repr__(self, work=False):
        return '\n'.join(
            '\n'.join(
                ''.join(
                    self.node_repr(x, y, work)[i]
                    for x in range(self.width)
                )
                for i in range(3)
            )
            for y in range(self.height)
        )

    def show_work_state(self):
        print(self.__repr__(True))

    def dead_ends(self, work=False):
        return [(x, y) for x in range(self.width) for y in range(self.height) if len(self.node_exits(x, y, work)) == 1]

    def cut_dead_end(self, x, y):
        ne = self.node_exits(x, y, work=True)
        if len(ne) != 1:
            return x, y
        self.dead_end_entrances.discard((x, y))
        offset = self.offset_dict[ne[0]]
        self.work_data[2 * y + 1 + offset[0]][2 * x + 1 + offset[1]] = 1
        return self.cut_dead_end(x + offset[1], y + offset[0])

    def trim_maze(self):
        dead_ends = self.dead_ends(True)
        for de in dead_ends:
            self.dead_end_entrances.add(self.cut_dead_end(*de))
        return self.dead_end_entrances

    def count_dead_end_entrances(self):
        return sum(
            len(self.node_exits(*node)) - len(self.node_exits(*node, True))
            for node in self.dead_end_entrances
        )

Example:
a = Maze([
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
])
print(a)

    o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o        x    
    |                          |        |                                   |        |    
    |                          |        |                                   |        |    
    o ------ o ------ o        o        o ------ o        o ------ o        o ------ o    
                      |        |                 |        |        |                      
                      |        |                 |        |        |                      
    x        o ------ o        x        o ------ o        x        o ------ o ------ o    
    |        |                          |        |                                   |    
    |        |                          |        |                                   |    
    o ------ o        o ------ o ------ o        o ------ o        o ------ o        o    
                      |                                   |        |        |        |    
                      |                                   |        |        |        |    
    o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o        o ------ o        o ------ o    
    |                 |                 |        |                 |                      
    |                 |                 |        |                 |                      
    o ------ o        o        o ------ o        o        x ------ o ------ o ------ o    
             |        |        |                 |                                   |    
             |        |        |                 |                                   |    
    o ------ o        x        o        o ------ o        o ------ x        o ------ o    
    |                          |        |                 |                 |             
    |                          |        |                 |                 |             
--- o        o ------ o        o        o ------ x        o ------ o        o ------ o    
    |        |        |        |                                   |                 |    
    |        |        |        |                                   |                 |    
    o        o        o ------ o        o ------ o ------ o ------ o        x        o    
    |        |                          |                                   |        |    
    |        |                          |                                   |        |    
    x        o ------ o ------ o ------ o        x ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o    
                                                          |                     


print(a.dead_ends())
# [(0, 2), (0, 9), (2, 6), (3, 2), (5, 7), (5, 9), (6, 2), (6, 5), (7, 6), (8, 8), (9, 0)]

a.cut_dead_end(0, 2)
a.show_work_state()

    o        o        o        o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o        x    
                               |        |                                   |        |    
                               |        |                                   |        |    
    o        o        o        o        o ------ o        o ------ o        o ------ o    
                               |                 |        |        |                      
                               |                 |        |        |                      
    o        o        o        x        o ------ o        x        o ------ o ------ o    
                                        |        |                                   |    
                                        |        |                                   |    
    o        o        o ------ o ------ o        o ------ o        o ------ o        o    
                      |                                   |        |        |        |    
                      |                                   |        |        |        |    
    o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o        o ------ o        o ------ o    
    |                 |                 |        |                 |                      
    |                 |                 |        |                 |                      
    o ------ o        o        o ------ o        o        x ------ o ------ o ------ o    
             |        |        |                 |                                   |    
             |        |        |                 |                                   |    
    o ------ o        x        o        o ------ o        o ------ x        o ------ o    
    |                          |        |                 |                 |             
    |                          |        |                 |                 |             
--- o        o ------ o        o        o ------ x        o ------ o        o ------ o    
    |        |        |        |                                   |                 |    
    |        |        |        |                                   |                 |    
    o        o        o ------ o        o ------ o ------ o ------ o        x        o    
    |        |                          |                                   |        |    
    |        |                          |                                   |        |    
    x        o ------ o ------ o ------ o        x ------ o ------ o ------ o ------ o    
                                                          |                               

print(a.trim_maze())
# {(0, 7), (2, 4), (7, 4), (8, 9), (7, 5), (6, 9), (5, 2)}

a.show_work_state()
                                                                                         
    o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o    
                                                                                          
                                                                                          
    o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o    
                                                                                          
                                                                                          
    o        o        o        o        o ------DEE       o        o        o        o    
                                        |        |                                        
                                        |        |                                        
    o        o        o ------ o ------ o        o ------ o        o        o        o    
                      |                                   |                               
                      |                                   |                               
    o ------ o ------DEE       o        o        o        o ------DEE       o        o    
    |                                                              |                      
    |                                                              |                      
    o ------ o        o        o        o        o        o       DEE------ o ------ o    
             |                                                                       |    
             |                                                                       |    
    o ------ o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o ------ o    
    |                                                                       |             
    |                                                                       |             
---DEE       o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o ------ o    
                                                                                     |    
                                                                                     |    
    o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o        o    
                                                                                     |    
                                                                                     |    
    o        o        o        o        o        o       DEE------ o ------DEE------ o    
                                                          |                               

a.count_dead_end_entrances()
# 8


Interesting cutting dead end approach~~ let me try and get back to you if any corner case~~ tysm!

The logic works for all the mazes. Thanks!

You're welcome. But of course, the logic would fail for mazes with islands (loops).
